# Passing options array to EventListerner from a FormType

Tags: symfony

I have a FormType to be reused for editing & creating records. This form has one entity field which renders into a select populated depending the record id, so I need to skip this field when creating a new record. I read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html and after changing some roots, everything seems to be fine until I'm trying to edit an existing record when I get stuck with this error:

ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: options in /Users/a77/Documents/DEV/UVox Com/src/Acme/DemoBundle/EventListener/VenueFieldSubscriber.php line 32

Mi VenuesFormType is :

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\VenueFieldSubscriber;


class VenuesType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('password', 'text')
                ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save', 'attr' => array('data-loading-text' => 'loading', 'class' => "btn btn-primary")))

                ->addEventSubscriber(new VenueFieldSubscriber());
    }

 /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Venues'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'acme_demobundle_venues';
    }

}
```

And my VenueFieldSubscriber is :

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class VenueFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $product = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (!$product || null === $product->getId()) {
            // no action for new record
        } else {

            $form->add('user', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:Users',
                'property' => 'username',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->Where('u.venue=?1')
                            ->andWhere('u.usertype >1')
                            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC')
                            ->setParameter(1, $options['attr']['venueid']);
        }
            ));


        }
    }
```

Any ideas, what I'm missing ? $options['attr']['venueid'] should give me the id of the record I'm editing... Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that after

```
$product = $event->getData();
```

`$product` is an object of `Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Venues` class.

Then instead of

```
->setParameter(1, $options['attr']['venueid'])
```

try

```
->setParameter(1, $product->getId())
```

Comment: That's the solution, also updating use($options) to use($product). Thanks mate!